Can a bird fly if the polar atmosphere is this thin?
Imagine, if you will, a fantasy world so fantastical in regards to physics that one of its telltale signs of disregarding the laws of physics is how atmospheric density is tied to latitude.  At zero degrees (shortened and popularized into the "equator"), the atmosphere is twice as dense as Earth's atmosphere, which would make the already hot, wet and humid tropics even hotter, wetter and more humid than on Earth, as thicker atmospheres hold more heat and therefore more moisture.  But at 90 degrees on both hemispheres, the density has dropped to 0.24 (or 24% as dense as Earth's), which might make the poles even colder than they already are on Earth.  (Though, in order to clarify for the sole purpose of deciding the answer, the ozone layer is one inch thick, eight times thicker than Earth's.)
Now this question concerns birds who, like with back home, would need to fly to the poles to spend the short but very intense summers, because to get to and from their arctic breeding grounds, they still have to fly.  And if the poles have atmospheres of 0.24 Earths, would they still do that?  If not, then what is the minimum required atmospheric density for birds the size of ordinary birds (the largest including the likes of Pelagornis and Argentavis) to fly without overexerting themselves to death?

Some pretty big birds, for example storks, can fly at about 5,000 metres (15,000 foots) altitude during their migration, where air pressure is about half of the pressure at sea level. Some kinds of geese and swans are supposed to have been recorded flying above 8,000 meters altitude, where the pressure is about one third of the pressure at sea level.
(Other studies say that the famous bar-headed goose (Anser indicus) rarely flies above 7,000 meters altitude, staying below 6,000 meters if it can. It is still very impressive.)

It's possible
Assuming your planet's atmosphere has its pressure declining linearly with latitude, with 2.0 start and 0.24 end, your birds would likely stop in mid to high latitudes (60-70 degrees) as the atmosphere would become too highlandish for most birds to fly or survive. However, some birds will be able to reach the pole. There is a practical evidence that Rueppel's vulture can reach heights of 11300 m, the atmospheric pressure there is below 0.24 atm (0.213 atm according to this calculator), so birds can fly in such an atmosphere. But, with those vultures having a very special adaptation to low partial pressure of oxygen and your nominal pressure of 2.0 atm, it's quite possible that if such birds would develop in your world, they won't cross some latitude where atmosphere would become just too thick for them.
Less adapted birds would have difficulties with keeping breath at higher atmospheric pressure than what's at your poles, even the second-highest in the list, a common crane, flies at 10000 m at 0.26 atm pressure, and likely experiences troubles maintaining prolonged flights. Also I expect that your planet has less dense atmosphere with height, so having 0.24 atm at the pole at zero elevation does not necessarily mean that at 1 km height the pressure is not 0.24 atm as well; this, if true, means that in order to reach the pole that crane would have to travel just over the treetops, if there are any, and take risks being attacked by land-based inhabitants, and might not reach the pole even then. Anything less adapted will not cross the border beyond some 80-85 degrees latitude, and common birds of Earth would not be able to reach far beyond 65 degrees latitude.
